# How to Hide Server Side Code From Client?

Tags: php, sql, backend

How do you hide server-side code from the client? What is to stop a person visiting my site from clicking "View Source" and seeing all of the server side code?

Comment: you mean  the browswer  html, javascript, css  code ?

Comment: php code will not be displayed in the view source.

Comment: if you see php on your site what you use 'view source' your doing something really wrong.

Comment: Is this a joke? Everything prevents them because the code is ON THE SERVER.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any code between `<?php` and `?>` will be executed on the server and not sent to the client. No special steps are required.

Answer (score 0):

If you see you PHP code in the browser, your web server do **not** execute it. So you have to check your server settings. Maybe PHP isn't installed or activated.